# Total number of Batch jobs decreases during execution. Why that?

Tags: apex, batch

A customer of my managed package is experiencing a long running batch job to change the number of total jobs during the run?

1. How can that be?
2. Is this an internal optimization at Salesforce?
3. Or did other users delete records that were queried in start()?
4. Should I open a case in such cases or can I rely on the status message "finished successfully"?

Comment: Found a similar (unanswered) question in the Salesforce Developer forum: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000091OZIAY

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Did you open a case?

Comment: Yes we did. (Case no. 15516557) I will report my results here.

Comment: Hmm wonder if you will get the "Developer support is not offered unless you have premier support. Please post your question on the developer forums. Case Closed".......I really hope they help you...

Answer (score 3):

The root cause is platform bug described in this Known Issue:

> In Spring'17 apex batch class (Database.Batchable) doesn't process all
>   the batches if batch execute method takes long time to run but within
>   limits. It stops processing batches after some number of processed
>   records and finishes unexpectedly. No error is reported, no exception
>   is thrown.

see [Known Issue : Batch Apex job finishes unexpectedly in Spring'17 without processing all specified records](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A000000esVNQAY)