# batch apex terminated unexpectedly

Tags: batch

I have batch apex which updates Lead owner name, processing a huge number of records. Batch apex stops processing batches after some number of records are processed and finishes unexpectedly and shows Apex Job status = Completed. No error is reported, no exception is thrown. I check debug logs to see the value in count variable is less than what is expected. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
Public class MassUpdateOwner implements Database.Batchable<SObject>,Database.Stateful
{
   private Integer callCount = 0; 
   Public ID targetUserId; //used to capture new User ID
   Public MassUpdateOwner (String ownerUsername)   
   {
        User u = [select Id from User where Username = new user name limit 1];
        TargetUserId = u.Id;
   }
   Public Database.QueryLocator START(Database.BatchableContext ctx)
   {
        Return Database.getQueryLocator([select OwnerId from Lead]);
    }
   Public void EXECUTE(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<Lead> scope) 
   {
       List<Lead> leads = (List<Lead>) scope;
       For (Lead l: leads) 
       {
         l.OwnerId = targetUserId; 
      }
      callcount++;
    }
   Public void finish (Database.BatchableContext ctx) 
   {
        // Send an email or something
   }

Id batch Job Id = Database.executeBatch(new MassUpdateOwner(), 1); 
}
```

My question is should I run the batch apex again? Pls let me know.

Comment: I could not see any DML statement in your execute or finish method if its your complete code

Answer (score 1):

This may be the known issue in Spring '17: [Batch Apex job finishes unexpectedly in Spring'17 without processing all specified records](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A000000esVNQAY), which is currently in process of being released.

Comment: Let me know if your org is not on Spring '17 though - there's another issue that I'm investigating where a long-running batch process is hitting a CPU timeout and not being reported as a failure that may be a separate issue: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156902/has-anybody-seen-this-behavior-batch-jobs-failing-silently-on-cpu-timeout-excep

Comment: My orgz is not using spring 17